# How do I ensure unique ids in a Datastore project that comes from a backup?

Tags: google-app-engine, primary-key, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

If I backup and restore with the Google Datastore [backup utility](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/datastore-backing-up-restoring), numerical IDs are copied to the new Datastore.

The restoration "manually" assigns numerical IDs -- i.e., it is not using the auto-allocation.

Then, if I create new Entities using the default ID auto-allocation, it seems that I risk collisions. As stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities):

> [A]dvanced applications may sometimes wish to assign their own numeric
>   IDs manually to the entities they create. Be aware, however, that
>   there is nothing to prevent Datastore from assigning one of your
>   manual numeric IDs to another entity.

How do I avoid such collisions? I'd rather not switch to using `name`s, to maintain compatibility with my existing `id`-based code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of doing this.

Google's backup utility reserves IDs with `allocateIdRange` in the Google App Engine API. However, this functionality is *not available* through the Google Cloud Datastore API.

If you do not allocate-id-range, you risk putting Datastore  into an inconsistent state where you get an exception when you create  a new Entity with autoallocated ID.

(You might find some way to  just use  the GAE API, but that works only in a single project; it cannot copy from one project to another.)

Answer (score 3):

If you restore into the same project, it is just reassigning the existing IDs, not manually assigning 'new' Ids. This this case, you will not run into any issues with auto-allocation. As a related note, we track auto-assigned Ids per entity-group, so you cannot copy child entities from one group to another.

This works across projects due to internal APIs we can call.

Comment: "If you restore into the same project," Thanks. But I am restoring into a different project. Even if that was not in itself a requirement, it is essential for testing the backup-restore cycle. But from "This works across projects" I understand that subsequent auto-allocation of ID, even on this different project,  will not have any collections.